# How to check if SQL Server CE is installed on Windows CE

Tags: c#, windows-ce

How do I check if SQL Server CE is installed on Windows CE (in C#)?

Answer (score 1):

Although [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950550) is aimed at desktops, it seems to fit your needs as well. It specifies how to check the version, so I guess that in case it is not installed the registry key does not exist.

You can simply try it. Also, you can simply do registry diffs to see what is updated during the cab installation.